# How can I use javascript to capture a click and send the page to a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<li><a id="logout" 
            class="access button red"
            href="/MyAccount/Access/Logout"
            data-href="/MyAccount/Access/Logout"
            title="Logout"><span class="smaller">LOGOUT</span></a></li>
```

When the user goes to this link it shows "/MyAccount/Access/Logout" in the bottom of the browser screen.

Can I make it so the link uses javascript to go to the new location? Something like:

```
 $('#logout').click(function (e) {
            ???
            ???
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: Google "Javascript document.location"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="location='logout'; return false;">log out</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your href to "#"

In your logout function: 
    window.location = "/MyAccount/Access/Logout";

No need to prevent default...

Answer (score 0):

`<li><a id="logout" 
            class="access button red"
            href="#"
            title="Logout"><span class="smaller">LOGOUT</span></a></li>`

`$('#logout').click(function (e) { window.location="/MyAccount/Access/Logout"; });`

Answer (score 0):

Use "javascript:void(0)" for href attr of anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('#logout').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     window.location.href = 'your/new/location';
});
```